# cant match page to URI with next.js Error: The provided path `/` does not match the page: `/[slug]`

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to build a dynamic page with using Wordpress as the data source.

I am not getting getStaticProps and getStaticPaths correct and it is causing errors

```
Error: The provided path `/` does not match the page: `/[slug]`.
```

I have hard coded the page name now for testing purposes (ideally I would like to make it dynamic)  (I have tried making codesandbox for this, but I always seem to have trouble with next.js and codesandbox).

I navigate to http://localhost:3000/art-shows to test

this is my [slug].js page

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { getAllPagesWithSlug, getAllPagesBySlug } from '../lib/api'
import { CMS_NAME } from '../lib/constants'
import Header from '../components/header'



export default function Index() {

console.log(router.query)
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Head>
          <title>page</title>
        </Head>
       <Header />
        <Container>
         Hello World
          
        </Container>
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}


export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    
    
  const data = await getAllPagesBySlug('/art-shows')

  return {
    props: {
      page: data.page,
  
    },
  }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const allPages = await getAllPagesWithSlug()

  return {
    paths: allPages.edges.map(({ node }) => `${node.uri}`) || [],
    fallback: true,
  }
}
```

this is my connection  ../lib/api'

```
const API_URL = process.env.WORDPRESS_API_URL

async function fetchAPI(query, { variables } = {}) {
  const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

  if (process.env.WORDPRESS_AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN) {
    headers[
      'Authorization'
    ] = `Bearer ${process.env.WORDPRESS_AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN}`
  }

  const res = await fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query,
      variables,
    }),
  })

  const json = await res.json()
  if (json.errors) {
    console.error(json.errors)
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch API')
  }
  return json.data
}


  
export async function getAllPagesBySlug($id) {
  const data = await fetchAPI(`
    {
     
        page(id: $id, idType: URI) {
            content
            isFrontPage
            isPostsPage
            uri
            title(format: RAW)
            seo {
              title
              metaDesc
              metaRobotsNofollow
              metaRobotsNoindex
            }
            featuredImage {
              node {
                sourceUrl
              }
            }
          }
    }
  `)
  return data
}


export async function getAllPagesWithSlug() {
  const data = await fetchAPI(`
    {
      pages(first: 10000) {
        edges {
          node {
            uri
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  return data?.pages
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again. I had put all the blog into its own folder, I left pages in the root folder. I finally got it working as so.

[slug.js]  many changes

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Container from '../components/container'
import MoreStories from '../components/more-stories'
import HeroPost from '../components/hero-post'
import Intro from '../components/intro'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import { getAllPagesWithSlug, getAllPagesBySlug } from '../lib/api'
import { CMS_NAME } from '../lib/constants'
import Header from '../components/header'



export default function Page( {page} ) {


  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Head>
          <title></title>
        </Head>
       <Header />
        <Container>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: page.content }} />
        
          
        </Container>
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}




export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    
  const data = await getAllPagesBySlug(params.slug)
  console.log(data)
  
  
  return {
    props: {
      page: data.page,
  
    },
  }
}




export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const allPages = await getAllPagesWithSlug()

  return {
     
     //paths:  [ { params: { slug: '${node.uri}' } }  ],
    paths: allPages.edges.map(({ node }) => `/${node.slug}`) || [],
    fallback: true,
  }
}
```

and query modifications   (page(id: "${$id}", idType: URI) {)

```
export async function getAllPagesBySlug($id) {
  const data = await fetchAPI(`
    {
     
        page(id: "${$id}", idType: URI) {
            content
            isFrontPage
            isPostsPage
            uri
            content
            title(format: RAW)
            featuredImage {
              node {
                sourceUrl
              }
            }
          }
    }
  `)
  return data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all slugs, then your file should be named [...slug].js (Note the ... spread operator) then inside of the file use the useRouter() hook and extract an array of slugs like this:

```
 const router = useRouter();
 const slug   = router.query.slug || [];
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-darkness-ktpd2?file=/pages/%5B...slug%5D.js

If you fork the sandbox link above then you will have a nextjs template to use code codesandbox. If the above doesn't work, fork the sandbox and put your code in and let me know so I can look it over.

Comment: thank you for this.. before I get into that I have a couple questions if you don't mind.. im using the Wordpress next headless template.. it uses [slug].js to load all the blog posts..  but apparently i cant use slug for pages (according to GraphQL) I need to match with uri...  Should I use [uri].js   and why does [slug].js work for blog posts?

Comment: I haven't used the wordpress next headless template, just nextjs like in your example above. Can you send a link to the template you are using so I can look at the one you are working on? 

[slug].js is used to get dynamic pages inside of that directory. /blog/this-is-a-post will pass this-is-a-post to the [slug] file. This is why it is perfect for blog posts. However, /blog/this-is-a-post/more will not be passed as it is 1 slug deeper(a directory level).